# get last 3 object of model from database in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on blog project & I have 'Last posts' section for posts in car category
i want to get last 3 object of my model from db and send with context to template.

'car_post' : post.objects.filter(category__name = 'car')[:3]

I tried this code but i think it shows first 3 post in db

what can i do?

Comment: Share the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the queryset with [**`.reverse()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#reverse):

```
post.objects.filter(category__name='car').reverse()[:3]
```

but very likely you can this more effective and descriptive if you can order, for example with a field like `created_at`, then it is:

```
post.objects.filter(category__name='car').order_by('-created_at')[:3]
```

this is also better in the sense that a `QuerySet`, unless ordered somehow, does not guarantee any ordering, so depending on the database, it can each time return objects in a different order.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`post`</s> to `Post`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct list slicing to retrieve the last 3 elements inside an iterable

```
post.objects.filter(category__name = 'car')[-3:]
```

Comment: This will not work for a `QuerySet`: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets (negative indexing). While that would perhaps be possible, the developers of Django currently did not implement this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/query.py#L425-L426 here it checks if the `k.start` and `k.stop` are `None` (not specified) or have a positive value.